# How to change the functionality of FILE_EXISTS_RENAME?

Tags: 7, files

I am using `files_save_upload` function to save the file. Here, I can use  `FILE_EXISTS_RENAME` this to rename the current file name if already this name existed. By default it rename by appending _indexes(0,1,2..). But I want to append some other things not the default one. So how can I achieve this? Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: That hook is just for the database object, it won't change the filename on disk @JimmyKo. It's for overriding timestamp/status/etc

Comment: @Clive True, I didn't use this hook for long time. Just guess it may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do it without changing the core function [`file_create_filename`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_create_filename/7.x). That could obviously have unwanted side-effects for other parts of the system, and make updating difficult.

If you have to do it differently for whatever reason, you should write your own function and use that instead. Once you see how much code you need to copy and maintain from `file_save_upload` and `file_create_filename`, though, you might think twice about whether it's worth it.